# How to calculate size of a struct in C?

Tags: c++, c, struct

I have the following Structs

```
struct node{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};
```

And I think that the size must be greater than sizeof(integer).

But it's confusing how to calculate the whole size of this struct.

So how to caculate the size?

I mean I want to calculate it manually by hand, not by computer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, size of structure is addition of size of each member field. But compiler may add some extra bytes for padding/align members appropriately.

So in your case,

```
sizeof(struct node) = sizeof(int) + sizeof(struct node *) + sizeof(struct node *)
                 12 = 4 + 4 + 4  (on 32-bit)
                 20 = 4 + 8 + 8  (on 64-bit)
```

This is general guideline may differ depending upon compiler/platform you choose.

Answer (score 6):

The size is at least `sizeof(int) + sizeof(struct node *) + sizeof(struct node *)`. But it may be more as the compiler is allowed to add *padding bytes* to your structure if it wishes.

How big `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(struct node*)` are depends on your system. They are likely to be 4 bytes each if you have a 32-bit system, or they could be 8 bytes if you have a 64-bit system. But really the only way to know for sure is to use the compiler to print out the size.

Answer (score 5):

If you are talking about a 32-bit application, integers, and pointers are 4 bytes.
Thus, your struct is 12 bytes in size.

```
struct node{
    int value;         // 0x0 - 0x4
    struct node *next; // 0x4 - 0x8
    struct node *prev; // 0x8 - 0xC
};
```

Assembly:

```
struct [0xDEADBEEF] {
    int 0x0;
    struct node *0x4;
    struct node *0x8;
};
```

**Side Note** A memory pointer read on [[0xDEADBEEF]+0x0] would return the current value of node->value and so on.

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof (struct node)` is the size in bytes of your structure.

It is equivalent to:

```
=    sizeof (int)
  +  potential unnamed padding1
  +  sizeof (struct node *)
  +  potential unnamed padding2
  +  sizeof (struct node *)
  +  potential unnamed padding3
```

The size of the padding between the members and at the end of the structure is implementation defined.

Comment: From the question: *I mean I want to caculate it manually by hand, not by computer...*

Answer (score 1):

You cannot calculate the exact size by hand. All you can figure out is that it will be atleast the sum of the sizes of its members.

i.e. in this case it will be atleast be `sizeof(int) + 2 * sizeof(struct node *)`, whatever these sizes are on your system.

It may be larger than this minimum size because of [padding](http://c-faq.com/struct/endpad.html), [alignment](http://c-faq.com/struct/padding.html).

Answer (score 1):

c++:
the correct way is to initialize `int plain_size()` method for each structure you need.

```
struct anotherstruct {
  ...
  static int plain_size(){...};
}

struct struct1 {
  int a;
  int b;
  anotherstruct c;

  static int plain_size() {
    return sizeof(a)+sizeof(b)+anotherstruct::plain_size();
  }
}
```

remember that this size maybe not equal to memory size allocated for structure